What happened to Hari, the son of Tarakaksha (one of Tripurasuras)?
This chapter of Karna Parva from Mahabharata mentiones about Hari, the son of Tarakaksha revived the demons by throw their dead body into a lake.

Tarakaksha had a heroic and mighty son named Hari. He underwent the austerest of penances, upon which the Grandsire became gratified with him. When the god was gratified, Hari solicited a boon of him, saying, 'Let a lake start into existence in our city, such that persons, slain by means of weapons, may, when thrown into it, come out with life, and with redoubled strength.' Obtaining this boon, the heroic Hari, son of Tarakaksha, created a lake, O lord, in his city, that was capable of reviving the dead.

But, it's unknown that what happens to Hari, while his father was slain by Lord Shiva and his grandfather Tarakasura was slain Lord Kartikeya.
So, my question is, what happened to Hari? Did any scripture mention about it?
